# Failed to install: xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard on OSX 10.6.8

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, osx-snow-leopard

I need to compile some apps with the iOS 5 SDK so I discovered I need to upgrade from xcode 3 to xcode 4.

My mac is on OSX 10.6.8, and I downloaded xcode_4.2_and_ios_5_sdk_for_snow_leopard.dmg from my iOS developer account. The image opens fine, does a check to confirm it can be installed, etc. but when I try the install, I get

"the installation failed. an unknown installation error occurred"

How can I fix this problem? Is there a log file to check?

Comment: I'm running 10.6.8 with Xcode 4.2/iOS5. I encountered that error not long back (after a disaster upgrading to iOS5.1 - which is incompatible for dev with 10.6.8 - and trying the various hacks to get it to work). I think I had to install XCode 4 first and then install 4.2 over that to get back to a functional install. HTH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this sounds ridiculous, set your computer clock to 1/1/2012 and it will install.

I had exactly the same issue.  There is some date / time issue with Xcode's installer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a proper solution at https://superuser.com/questions/410573/cant-install-xcode-on-os-x-snow-leopard :

Install this: [Apple Software Installer Update 1.0.](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1512)

About Apple Software Installer Update 1.0: "This update addresses an issue that may prevent certain Apple software from installing. This update is recommended for all users running Mac OS X 10.6.8."

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure that you can instal xcode 4 on OSX 10.6 :/ 
i have face this before and they said you have to upgrade to  OSX 10.7 to install xcode 4